# R - unlist nested list of dates

Tags: r, date, nested-lists

I have the below nested list of dates. I would need to unlist and then to get unique list of dates starting from the earliest date to the latest date.

```
> str(datetemp)
List of 3
 $ FCX : Date[1:5747], format: "1995-07-10" "1995-07-11" "1995-07-12" "1995-07-13" ...
 $ MAT : Date[1:9164], format: "1982-01-04" "1982-01-05" "1982-01-06" "1982-01-07" ...
 $ MSFT: Date[1:8104], format: "1986-03-13" "1986-03-14" "1986-03-17" "1986-03-18" ...
```

The below strip the date class and return a list of numeric.

```
datetemp <- sort(unique(unlist(datetemp)))
```

I googled and read that unlist will strip the date class and return as numeric and some examples show do.call on a list of dates.

I am new to R and would appreciate if anyone could show me how I can apply do.call to nested list to get the required output.

Thank you.

Comment: It's an annoying situation, but you can coerce back to Date class if you specify the origin (i.e. [the Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)): `as.Date(unlist(datetemp), origin = "1970-01-01")` The harder to explain but technically better approach is to use `do.call` to use `datetemp` as parameters for `c`: `do.call(c, datetemp)`

Answer (score 2):

One option is to coerce back to the Date class after `unlist` drops it. To do so, you'll need to specify the `origin` from which the integers are counted, which is [the Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), i.e. `1970-01-01`.

```r
datetemp <- list(FCX = structure(c(9321, 9322, 9323, 9324), class = "Date"), 
                 MAT = structure(c(4386, 4387, 4388, 4389), class = "Date"), 
                 MSFT = structure(c(5915, 5916, 5919, 5920), class = "Date"))

datetemp2 <- as.Date(unlist(datetemp), origin = "1970-01-01")
datetemp2
#>         FCX1         FCX2         FCX3         FCX4         MAT1 
#> "1995-07-10" "1995-07-11" "1995-07-12" "1995-07-13" "1982-01-04" 
#>         MAT2         MAT3         MAT4        MSFT1        MSFT2 
#> "1982-01-05" "1982-01-06" "1982-01-07" "1986-03-13" "1986-03-14" 
#>        MSFT3        MSFT4 
#> "1986-03-17" "1986-03-18"
```

A better approach is to use `do.call`, which splices a list in as the parameters of a call and evaluates it, so if you use `do.call(c, list(1, 2))`, it effectively calls `c(1, 2)`.

```r
datetemp3 <- do.call(c, datetemp)
datetemp3
#>         FCX1         FCX2         FCX3         FCX4         MAT1 
#> "1995-07-10" "1995-07-11" "1995-07-12" "1995-07-13" "1982-01-04" 
#>         MAT2         MAT3         MAT4        MSFT1        MSFT2 
#> "1982-01-05" "1982-01-06" "1982-01-07" "1986-03-13" "1986-03-14" 
#>        MSFT3        MSFT4 
#> "1986-03-17" "1986-03-18"
```

Sorting and dropping duplicates drops names, which is probably good:

```r
unique(sort(datetemp3))
#>  [1] "1982-01-04" "1982-01-05" "1982-01-06" "1982-01-07" "1986-03-13"
#>  [6] "1986-03-14" "1986-03-17" "1986-03-18" "1995-07-10" "1995-07-11"
#> [11] "1995-07-12" "1995-07-13"
```

Comment: `unlist(datetemp) %>% \`class<-\`(class(datetemp[[1]])))` allows you to avoid having to remember what the Unix epoch is. Doesn't really matter since `do.call` is the better approach anyway.

Comment: Good call. It's easier to read without piping in this case, though: `datetemp2 <- unlist(datetemp); class(datetemp2) <- class(datetemp[[1]])`

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten the list with `do.call(c, ...)`, while keeping the date type.

```
ll <- lapply(7:9, function(x) as.Date(sample(7000:7020, x), origin="1970-01-01"))

unique(do.call(c, ll))
```